# Subdag not executed and not shown as 'success'

Tags: python, airflow

I have been experimenting with 'example_subdag_operator' in airflow. After I changed the 'start_date' to `datetime.now()` and then manually trigger a dag run. The operator is green, but when I zoomed into the subdag itself, nothing is executed (white in graph view) and 'Run' drop down is empty. \

I use the newest version built from master. I also tested on pip released version. Still the same issue \

Is this a bug? Or I missed something?

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator

from airflow.example_dags.subdags.subdag import subdag


DAG_NAME = 'example_subdag_operator'

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime.now(),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_NAME,
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval="@once",
)

start = DummyOperator(
    task_id='start',
    default_args=args,
    dag=dag,
)

section_1 = SubDagOperator(
    task_id='section-1',
    subdag=subdag(DAG_NAME, 'section-1', args),
    default_args=args,
    dag=dag,
)

some_other_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='some-other-task',
    default_args=args,
    dag=dag,
)

section_2 = SubDagOperator(
    task_id='section-2',
    subdag=subdag(DAG_NAME, 'section-2', args),
    default_args=args,
    dag=dag,
)

end = DummyOperator(
    task_id='end',
    default_args=args,
    dag=dag,
)

start.set_downstream(section_1)
section_1.set_downstream(some_other_task)
some_other_task.set_downstream(section_2)
section_2.set_downstream(end)
```

[subdag operator success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ofut.png)

[subdag not executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0MAM.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. It is advised not to use dynamic values for start_date especially *datetime.now()*. The task is triggered once the period closes, and in theory an *@hourly* DAG would never get to an hour after now as *now()* moves along.

Source : 
[https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date]